# Java Problem - Locks and conditions w/ Threads

Tags: java, monitor

java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException is what I get with a nasty stack trace.

```
final Condition[] threads = new Condition[maxThreads];
myclass()
{
for (int i =0; i<maxThreads; i++)
            threads[i] = mutex.newCondition();
}    
public void test()
{

mutex.lock();
   int id = threadCount;
   threadCount++;
mutex.unlock();
threads[id].await();
}
```

When I call test with multiple threads it generates the error above. It is caused by the await line. I am hesitant to used synchronized because I want all threads to be able to await.

Comment: @Mike Daniels: `mutex` is supposedly the `Lock` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call await WHILE you hold the lock on mutex. So the code should be:

```
mutex.lock();
try {
   // do your stuff
   threads[id].await();
} finally {
   mutex.unlock();
}
```

The reason I added the try / finally is to ensure that the lock is released even if you throw an exception.

It is probably also worth noting that you can only call `signal` on your conditions while holding the lock on mutex as well.  You are able to get a lock on the mutex, even though you got a lock before calling await, because calling `await` causes the waiting thread to release its lock while it waits.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I felt like elaborating. Hope you don't mind! :)

Comment: @noob I was elaborating at the same time it looks like :o, +1 on yours

Answer (score 3):

In practice, you should `await` as such:

```
mutex.lock();
try
{
    threads[threadCount++].await();
}
finally
{
    mutex.unlock();
}
```